# How to determine a missing reference

Tags: model-view-controller, reference

I reinstalled VS. I loaded my solution and there some unresolved references. In particular: **system.web.mvc**. How can I find out what version of this dll needs to be installed?

Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should depend on the .NET Framework version your project uses. Just add a reference to the DLL of the same major version, such as 4.0.0.0.